# SQL NESTED JOIN NOT USING WHERE

Tags: sql, join, group-by, db2, sql-order-by

What is the current price of  each product?  Display product code, product description, unit, and its current price. Always assume that NOT ALL products HAVE unit price BUT you need to display it even if it has no unit price on it. without using WHERE script

Product Table

1. ***prodCode***
2. description
3. unit

PriceHist Table

1. ***prodCode***
2. ***effDate***
3. unitPrice

This is my work... Please Help me to improve my anwswer.

```
SELECT p.prodCode, p.description, p.unit, MAX(ph.unitPrice)  "Current Price" 
FROM product p 
INNER JOIN priceHist AS ph 
ON p.prodCode = ph.prodCode
GROUP BY p.prodCode, p.description, p.unit
ORDER BY MAX(ph.unitPrice);
```

Someone said I NEED TO USE PRICEHIST TWICE

Comment: What do you want to improve?

Comment: i think my script is incomplete or missing. I not able to answer the question above

Comment: How do you want to deal with multiple effDate for prodCode? Can you provide some sample data for tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.prodCode, a.description, a.unit, SUM(b.unitPrice)
FROM ProductTable a
LEFT JOIN PriceHistTable b ON a.prodCode = b.prodCode
GROUP BY a.prodCode, a.description, a.unit, b.unitPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

User window functions and `left join`:

```
select . . . -- whatever columns you want
from products p left join
     (select ph.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p.prodcode order by effdate desc) as seqnum
      from pricehist ph
     ) ph
     on ph.prodcode = p.prodcode and ph.seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to select `unitPrice` for `prodCode` with *latest* `effDate`, below query should work. Explanation in comments.

```
select x.prodCode, x.description, x.unit, y.unitPrice
from Product x
left join (
   --- Create a table y with one row per (prodCode, effDate)
   --- choosing the latest effDate per prodCode
   select a.prodCode, a.effDate, a.unitPrice
   from PriceHist  a
   join (
       --- Create b as (prodCode, effDate)
       select prodCode, max(effDate) as maxEffDate
       from PriceHist
       group by prodCode
   ) b
   on a.prodCode = b.prodCode and a.effDate = b.maxEffDate
) y
on x.prodCode = y.prodCode
```

Comment: 1. You **must** qualify `prodCode` inside the subselect, since both a and b has this column, and you get an error otherwise. It's always better to qualify all columns to not make a reader guess on what column belongs to what table. 2. The "NOT ALL products HAVE unit price" phrase implies, that LEFT JOIN should be used, when `Product` is joined to the result of the subselect.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein done. Thanks for the improvement suggestions!